# Android Studio Chipmunk 'by viewModels()' Unresolved

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a developer who is developing Android in Korea.
This happened when I recently updated my Android Studio to the latest version of Chipmunk(2021.2.1 Patch 1).

The 'by viewModels()' part is starting to show a red mark, but it is running well.

This is mouse over message.

`Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch`

'activity-ktx' and 'fragment-ktx' are in the latest version. (1.5.0)

I suspect that the Gradle version is low, but the Gradle version is very difficult to update due to the composition of the project.

Applying it to multiple solutions doesn't improve the situation.
If who know anything about this issue, please share it.

```
android version : 2021.2.1 Patch 1
activity-ktx version : 1.5.0
fragment-ktx version : 1.5.0
gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl gradle version : 6.7.1
project build.gradle : 4.1.3
```

Comment: Have you tried, Invalidate cache and restart option?

Comment: @Kamal - I've already tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like this has been reported to the Android Kotlin Plugin tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231997048 which got kicked over to the IntelliJ Kotlin tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-22124/Kotlin-superclass-resolution-chooses-incorrect-version-of-the-library which may in turn be caused by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-22012/Parent-class-resolution-fails-for-jars-with-META-INFTRANSITIVE -- we shall see!

Comment: @ksparrow - Let me check the link you gave me. Thank you.